# Finding the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1-\frac{1}{3})^2(1-\frac{1}{6})^2(1-\frac{1}{10})^2...(1-\frac{1}{n(n+1)/2})^2$

Tags: calculus, limits, infinite-product

Any hints on how to find the following limit ?.

I haven't been able to figure it out still.
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\, 1 - \frac{1}{3}\, \right)^{2}
\left(\, 1 - \frac{1}{6}\, \right)^{2}\left(\, 1 - \frac{1}{10}\, \right)^{2}\ldots\left[\, 1 - \frac{1}{n\left(\, n + 1\, \right)/2}\, \right]^{2}
$$

Pardon me if it's a silly question.

Edit: Solved upto this much

$$
\prod_{n = 2}^{\infty}\left[\, 1-\frac{2}{n\left(\, n + 1\, \right)}\, \right] =
\prod_{n = 2}^{\infty}\left(\, \frac{n + 2}{n + 1}\,\frac{n - 1}{n}\, \right)
$$

I did'nt notice most of the terms cancel out.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We have
$$ \prod_{n=2}^{+\infty}\left(1-\frac{2}{n(n+1)}\right)=\prod_{n=2}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{n+2}{n+1}\cdot\frac{n-1}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{3} $$
(it is a telescopic product) hence you limit equals $\color{red}{\large\frac{1}{9}}$.

Comment: I don't see the point of the middle step: in particular, why write the reciprocal and then reciprocate again? Just write $1-\frac{2}{n(n+1)}=\frac{n(n+1)-2}{n(n+1)}=\frac{(n+2)(n-1)}{n(n+1)}$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic: I just wrote down my thoughts chain on-the-fly, but you are right, there is no need of such middle step. Removed.

Comment: no problem: I just thought I was missing something; was very confused about the introduction of the inverse. then I realized it was just your way of thinking through the calculation.

Comment: Now I am getting tired of being downvoted for no reason, daily. I am flagging my answer for mod intervention and I hope I'll get rid of this annoying behaviour.

Comment: @symplectomorphic. Using  Jack D'Aurizio's inspring solution, you could easily show that $$\prod_{n=2}^{p}\left(1-\frac{2}{n(n+1)}\right)=\frac{p+2}{3 p}$$

Comment: (+1) for the nice answer and for pointing out the problem of the downvoting without any sense.

Answer (score 3):

It may be interesting to see that, using the the Gamma function in the form $$\Gamma\left(z\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^{z-1}n!}{z\left(z+1\right)\cdots\left(z+n-1\right)}$$ we can prove that $$\prod_{n\geq0}\frac{\left(n+a\right)\left(n+b\right)}{\left(n+c\right)\left(n+d\right)}=\frac{\Gamma\left(c\right)\Gamma\left(d\right)}{\Gamma\left(a\right)\Gamma\left(b\right)},\, a+b=c+d
 $$ so $$\prod_{n\geq2}\frac{\left(n+2\right)\left(n-1\right)}{\left(n+1\right)n}=\prod_{n\geq0}\frac{\left(n+4\right)\left(n+1\right)}{\left(n+3\right)\left(n+2\right)}$$ $$=\frac{\Gamma\left(3\right)\Gamma\left(2\right)}{\Gamma\left(4\right)\Gamma\left(1\right)}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{3}}.$$